# Tomcat warning: "Setting property 'showServerInfo' to 'false' did not find a matching property"

Tags: tomcat

I'm trying to change my webapp so that it doesn't provide any details about the server type or version when an error is generated, as described in [this page](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/security-howto.html).  So in the META-INF/context.xml file of my webapp I have added an ErrorReportValve like this:

```
  <Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps"
        unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true"> 

   ...

    <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve" 
        showReport="false" 
        showServerInfo="false" />

   ...

  </Host>
```

But when I start tomcat I get this error message:

Feb 27, 2015 11:48:26 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Context/Valve} Setting property 'showReport' to 'false' did not find a matching property.

Feb 27, 2015 11:48:26 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Context/Valve} Setting property 'showServerInfo' to 'false' did not find a matching property.

(I am running tomcat 7.0.52 on Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS)

Can anyone suggest why the ErrorReportValve seems to be missing properties?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is my version of tomcat is too old - the properties weren't included until version 7.0.54:

http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/changelog.html